# firebase security rule using customClaims

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

The objective is to restrict storage access only to user who are authenticated in firebase and has a customClaims of role subscriber.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Allow read access only for authenticated users with the role of "subscriber"
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && (
        request.auth.customClaims.role == "subscriber"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

but getting the error:

> Error: simulator.rules line [6], column [9]. Property customClaims is undefined on object.

any help is appreciated the users are the google authenticated users and each has a customs role assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Custom claims are available in the `request.auth.token` variable, so:

```
request.auth.token.role == "subscriber"
```

If you run into similar problems going forward, I recommend checking these [questions about custom claims in Storage security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D%5Bfirebase-security%5D+custom+claims)/

Comment: still the same error `Error: simulator.rules line [6], column [9]. Property role is undefined on object.`

Comment: That's a different error message, and in fact shows that the `token` property **does** exist, while the `customClaims` property you used doesn't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

--- It sounds like the `role` claim doesn't exist in your token. Are you sure i has propagated already?

Comment: Note that the [auth:export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export) command of the Firebase CLI allows you to see the Custom Claims assigned to the Auth user accounts. The file returned by this command includes the claims.

Comment: the error was in the simulator, it is indeed working in the real connection